# What is the best approach to fetch a flag if objects are connected?

Tags: sql, hibernate, web-services, request, spring-data-jpa

Suppose, we have two entities\tables - Users and Games (could be anything instead). And a user can mark multiple games as a favourite. So we also have a user_favourite_game (user_id, game_id) table.

Then suppose, a user is fetching a list of all available games and some of them should have the "favourite" flag = true (pagination is used, so we'll assume 20 games are fetched each time). So I see two approaches here:

1. We can make one request populating the "favourite" field, e. g.

```
SELECT 
    g.*, 
    ufg.game_id IS NOT NULL AS favourite
FROM
    games g LEFT JOIN
    user_favourite_game ufg ON ufg.user_id = :userId AND g.id = ufg.game_id
ORDER BY
    g.id;
```

2. We can select the games and then perform 20 requests to check whether a game is of user's favourites.

Which approach is better to use and why? Any other ideas?

On the last project, we used the second approach because of the complexity of computations required for each entity. So it was a lot more complicated rather than in the example above and close to impossible to be calculated inside a single query.

But in general, it seems to me that in such simple cases a single query with JOIN should run faster than 20 simple queries. Although, I'm not sure how it will behave when we'll have a lot of data in user_favourite_game table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firing 20 queries(irrespective of how simple they are) will always slow your application. Factors includes network cost, query running etc.

You should fire one query to get page of available games and then make another query to get list of "favorite" games of that user by passing ids of games present in that page. Then set/unset the flag by looping the result. This way you will make only 2 DB calls and it will improve performance significantly.

Comment: Thanks! It totally makes sense and can be applied to each service call without rewriting the query)

Comment: You welcome. may I please get an upvote and "answered" clicked please :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the database for what it's designed to do and have it give you the results as part of your original query.

The time your DB will spend performing the outer join on the user favorite game table will likely be less than the network overhead of 20 separate requests for the favorite flag.

Make sure the tables are indexed appropriate as they grow and have accurate statistics.

This isn't a hard and fast rule, and actual performance testing should guide, but I have observed plenty of applications that were harmed by network chattiness. If your round-trip cost for each request is 250ms, your 20 calls will be very expensive. If your round-trip cost is 1ms, people might never notice.

Comment: Thanks! I generally agree :) But maybe I didn't specify it correctly: there won't be 20 HTTP requests. Frontend client will make only one, but the backend will make 20 requests to the database. I mean queries. Yeah, I should've probably called it queries :)

Comment: Sounds good--follow your nose then. If you find that those 20 requests are instantaneous then it's probably not an issue. I would still try to design this in a way where I wasn't making 20 calls to the DB no matter how close the servers are.